# Create matrix table in JS with HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My code is below.
I have problem about create matrix table with span cell.
Please see in picture output attached,

- I saw extension beyond cell the right of table.
- In column 'Pareto', if same (Process name) category, data is paste in only that cell(delemiter by ",")

```js
// Your data
var data = [{
    Process: 'PCAL',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER META 1 Serdes 142',
    Fail: '1'
  },
  {
    Process: 'CAL',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  },
  {
    Process: 'FVT',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '50.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '50.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER Lane 12',
    Fail: '3'
  },
  {
    Process: 'FVT',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '50.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '50.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER',
    Fail: '1'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Module Power',
    Fail: '4'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Module A Power',
    Fail: '14'
  },
  {
    Process: 'EXS',
    DATE: '30 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '3',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  }
];

// Extract unique dates and sort them in ascending order
var uniqueDates = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.DATE))].sort();

// Create the matrix table
document.write('<table>');
document.write('<tr><th rowspan="2">DATE</th>');

// Create sub-column headers for each unique date
uniqueDates.forEach(date => {
  document.write(`<th colspan="5">${date}</th>`);
});

document.write('</tr>');
document.write('<tr>');

// Create sub-column headers for ['Qty','FTY','RTY','Pareto','Fail']
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueDates.length; i++) {
  document.write('<th>Qty</th><th>FPY</th><th>RTY</th><th>Pareto</th><th>Fail</th>');
}

document.write('</tr>');

// Populate the table with data
var uniqueProcesses = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Process))];
uniqueProcesses.forEach(process => {
  document.write(`<tr><td rowspan="5">${process}</td>`);

  uniqueDates.forEach(date => {
    var rowData = data.filter(item => item.Process === process && item.DATE === date);

    if (rowData.length > 0) {
      document.write(`
                                <td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].QTY}</td>
                                <td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].FPY}</td>
                                <td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].RTY}</td>
                                <td>${rowData.map(item => item.Pareto)}</td>
                                <td>${rowData.map(item => item.Fail)}</td>
                                `);
    } else {
      // If no data for the process and date, insert empty cells
      document.write('<td rowspan="5"></td><td rowspan="5"></td><td rowspan="5"></td><td></td><td></td>');
    }
  });
  document.write('</tr>');

  // Insert four additional rows for each Process row
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    document.write('<td></td>'); // Empty cell for the "Process" column
    uniqueDates.forEach(() => {
      document.write('<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
    });
    document.write('</tr>');
  }
});

document.write('</table>');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqcVM.jpg)

- I don't need extension beyond cell the right of table.
- I need to add pareto value to column by each row of column pareto.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I hope it can help you:

```js
var data = [{
    Process: 'PCAL',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER META 1 Serdes 142',
    Fail: '1'
  },
  {
    Process: 'CAL',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  },
  {
    Process: 'FVT',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '50.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '50.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER Lane 12',
    Fail: '3'
  },
  {
    Process: 'FVT',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '50.0',
    QTY: '2',
    RTY: '50.0',
    Pareto: 'Client BER',
    Fail: '1'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '28 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Module Power',
    Fail: '4'
  },
  {
    Process: 'ESS',
    DATE: '29 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '0.0',
    QTY: '1',
    RTY: '0.0',
    Pareto: 'Module A Power',
    Fail: '14'
  },
  {
    Process: 'EXS',
    DATE: '30 Nov 2023',
    FPY: '100.0',
    QTY: '3',
    RTY: '100.0',
    Pareto: 'None',
    Fail: 'None'
  }
];
let uniqueProcesses = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Process))];
let uniqueDates = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.DATE))].sort();
let table = document.createElement("Table");
let header = table.createTHead();
let headerRow = header.insertRow();
headerRow.innerHTML = "<th rowspan=\"2\">Date</th>";
uniqueDates.forEach(date => {
  headerRow.innerHTML += `<th colspan="5">${date}</th>`;
});
headerRow = header.insertRow();
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueDates.length; i++) {
  headerRow.innerHTML += '<th>Qty</th><th>FPY</th><th>RTY</th><th>Pareto</th><th>Fail</th>';
}


uniqueProcesses.forEach(process => {
  let row = table.insertRow();
  let firstCell = row.insertCell();
  firstCell.innerHTML = process;
  firstCell.rowSpan = 5;
  uniqueDates.forEach(date => {
    let rowData = data.filter(item => item.Process === process && item.DATE === date);
    if (rowData.length > 0) {
      row.innerHTML += `<td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].QTY}</td>`;
      row.innerHTML += `<td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].FPY}</td>`;
      row.innerHTML += `<td rowspan="5">${rowData[0].RTY}</td>`;
      row.innerHTML += `<td>${rowData.map(item => item.Pareto)}</td>`;
      row.innerHTML += `<td>${rowData.map(item => item.Fail)}</td>`;
    } else {
      row.innerHTML += '<td rowspan="5"></td><td rowspan="5"></td><td rowspan="5"></td><td></td><td></td>';
    }
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (let j = 0; j < (uniqueDates.length * 2); j++) {
      row.innerHTML += "<td></td>";
    }
  }
});
document.body.append(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```